# Is it is possible through Email Rules to Move received Emails from Inbox into Folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, webmail

I have 2000+ messages in inbox now i wish to move into folders using rules without drag and drop? So is there any way to move received mails which is already read from inbox to appropriate folders based on senders email address by using `Email Rules` in MS Outlook 2007 & Outlook web app(Outlook web mail).....?

If any other ways are exists please mention those or share appropriate link..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use outlook rules to achieve it.

**file-> Manage Rules and Alerts -> New Rule -> Move message from someone to folder**

notice that you will have to check the checkbox:
 **"run this rule now on messages allready in Inbox"** 
on the last screen.
it will apply this rule as you requested.

good luck

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/09/29/outlook2.png

Comment: Ya its working fine in my local machines's outlook.....But i cant able to find this option in outlook web app(Outlook web mail) is there any way to do like same in outlook web app ?????

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007 has inbuilt feature called as Rules and Alerts to enable you to just do that.

Create a rule from scratch

To create a rule by choosing your own conditions, actions, and exceptions, do the following:

1. In the Navigation Pane, click Mail.
2. On the Tools menu, click Rules and Alerts.
3. Click New Rule.
4. Under Start from a blank rule, select either Check messages when they arrive or Check messages after sending, and then click Next.
5. Under Step 1: Select condition(s), select the conditions that you want the messages to meet for the rule to apply.
   Under Step 2: Edit the rule description, click an underlined value if you have not done so already, and then click Next.
   Under Step 1: Select action(s), select the action that you want the rule to take when the specified conditions are met.
   Under Step 2: Edit the rule description, click an underlined value if you have not done so already, and then click Next.
   Under Step 1: Select exception(s), select any exceptions to the rule, and then click Next.

   6.To finish creating the rule, enter a name for the rule, and then select any other options that you want.
6. If you want to run this rule on messages that already are in one of your folders, select the Run this rule now on messages already in "folder" check box.
7. To apply this rule to all your e-mail accounts and the Inbox associated with each account, select the Create this rule on all accounts check box.
8. Click Finish.

Comment: Ya its working fine in my local machines's outlook.....But i cant able to find this option in outlook web app(Outlook web mail) is there any way to do like same in outlook web app ?????